# USB to Serial Adapter

Tags: windows-7, usb, port, serial

OS is Windows 7 home edition, with a Prolific USB to Serial adapter. 
The issue is that after rebooting, Radio BOSS sends the command to the serial port adapter but the device does not recognize the text sent to it. 
After running a third party serial port software, the device reads the text just fine.

The command that Radio BOSS uses is:  send com7 *00X (X being numbers 1 through 4 which correspond to the input audio on the device.) 
As state above, the device is able to read that it is from com7 with a quick blink on the front panels LED's, but does not switch to the input sent in the text portion of the command (say *001 for audio sent to the port).  * is the start of the string, first 0 is the device number, and the 01 used to define the port to switch.

Is it possible that usb port is interfering with the text portion of the command sent to the device? Device used is Broadcast Tools ss4.1 MLR Switcher/Router.

Comment: You've provided some ancillary information, but neglect to specify the most salient.  What is this *"third party serial port software"* that seems to fix the problem?  You also neglect to confirm that you have configured both sides of this serial link to the same configuration.  You carelessly assume that what *"Radio BOSS [sic]"* is is common knowledge. *"Is it possible that usb port is interfering ..."* -- Not likely.

Comment: Settings for the usb to serial adapter were set to the same rate as the default settings for the switcher/router, 9600, 8, n, 1. If it has to do with flow control then I can see the error of my ways. My guess is that it needs to be set to Xon / Xoff to get the flow to head in the right direction.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing some setup stages: A serial port has some parameters (baud rate, bit length, stop bit count, parity, flow control) that need to be set to the correct values.

I suspect you do not set them at all, resulting your writes to be unreadable by the device. The "3rd party software" then sets them, resulting in further writes to be readable.

Check out the `mode` command, it might help you.